# When click on checkbox neighbour is also passing to onClick

Tags: android, checkbox

I have the following layout. However when I press on a checkbox to either check or uncheck it then it is indicating to buttonOnCLick that more than one checkbox was pressed on. It seems like the amount of pressable area for each checkbox is bleeding over to it's neighbour. However the neighbour checkbox doesn't change check state. Any ideas what is going on here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NOC"
                android:id="@+id/txtNOC"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show"
                android:id="@+id/noc_show"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notify"
                android:id="@+id/noc_notify"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Opinion"
                android:id="@+id/txtOpinion"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show"
                android:id="@+id/opinion_show"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />


            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notify"
                android:id="@+id/opinion_notify"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alert"
                android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show"
                android:id="@+id/alerts_show"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />


            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notify"
                android:id="@+id/alerts_notify"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you know that the listener is being called for more than one button? What evidence do you have?

Comment: Also, please show your code for `buttonOnClick`.